# Difference between these 2 methods

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I am not able to spot why these 2 method behave differently. Only difference between the two is the sleep method call.

In the first method, I was expecting that second future execution will wait for first future to complete as it is dependent on the result of the first.

Please help me to understand why the behaviour is different for both the method or is there anything logically wrong in my code?

I have tried running in debug mode but still it gave the same result.

```java
public static void thenComposeWithSleep() {
        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
            return "Hello";
        }).thenCompose(value -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> value + " Then compose is been called"));
        completableFuture.thenAccept(System.out::println);
    }

public static void thenCompose() {
        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello")
                .thenCompose(value -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> value + " Then compose is been called"));
        completableFuture.thenAccept(System.out::println);
    }
```

Expected Output from first method : "Hello Then compose is been called".

Actual Output from first method : Empty String

Expected & Actual Output from second method are same.

Output : "Hello Then compose is been called"

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It prints correctly for me, after 5s sleep.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. This is bit strange. I have tried on both Eclipse & IntelliJ on windows 10. It prints nothing for first function. However, after adding "completableFuture.get();" in the first function, it prints correctly.

Comment: It prints nothing, because your program terminates before the five seconds elapsed. That’s why you should provide *complete* examples, capable of reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()
```

hands execution to

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool()
```

When this runs in daemon mode (which is default according to the Java7 documentation), if your main thread terminates all the uncompleted async tasks will be discarded and never complete.

So my guess is what you are assuming as an "Empty String" is actually

```
System.out::println
```

is not executing at all.

To illustrate this for the class

```
public class DaemonsAtPlay {

    public static void thenComposeWithSleep() {
        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
            return "Slept"; //HERE
        }).thenCompose(value -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> value + " Then compose is been called"));
        completableFuture.thenAccept(DaemonsAtPlay::report); //HERE
    }

    public static void thenCompose() {
        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello")
                .thenCompose(value -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> value + " Then compose is been called"));
        completableFuture.thenAccept(DaemonsAtPlay::report); //HERE
    }

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    static void report(String msg) {
        System.out.println("report: " + counter.incrementAndGet() + "; message: >" + msg + "<");
    }

    public static void executeMultiple(int iterations, boolean withsleep) {
        for(int i=0; i<iterations; ++i) {
            if(withsleep) {
                thenComposeWithSleep();
            } else {
                thenCompose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... none) throws Exception {
        executeMultiple(100, false);
        executeMultiple(100, true);
        report("exiting main");
    }
}
```

I get the output

```
report: 1; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 2; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 3; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 4; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 5; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 6; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 7; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 8; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 9; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 10; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 11; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 12; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 13; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 14; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 15; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 16; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 17; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 18; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 19; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 20; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 21; message: >Hello Then compose is been called<
report: 22; message: >exiting main<
```

Which illustrates that not only the 'slept' tasks but many of the 'unslept' tasks didn't terminate.

If you want to wait for all the CompletableFuture tasks to terminate you can use

```
CompletableFuture.join()
```

on the main thread.

Comment: As a side note, `.thenCompose(value -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> value + " Then compose is been called"))` is a convoluted version of `.thenApplyAsync(value -> value + " Then compose is been called"))`

Comment: @Evan Jones Thanks a lot. "CompletableFuture.join()"  was the missing piece. And Yes you are right that SOP in the compose method is not been executed at all.

Comment: @Holger Yes you are right. I have not reached to async version of these function as yet. Thanks for pointing it out.